# Printing elements of an array up to the key specified in C programming

Tags: c, arrays

I've been working on my coding skills and I have started my journey here. Since I'm stuck at one place and trying to figure it where I'm going wrong. The code goes like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int a[10],i,j,arr_size;

   printf("Enter the size of the array");
   scanf("%d",&arr_size);

   printf("Enter the array:");
   for(i=0;i<arr_size;i++)
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);

   //here key is 42
   //so we'll find the key and print the elements up to that
   for(j=0;j<arr_size;j++){
      if(j==42)
        break;

      //loop for the array up to the key
      for(i=0;i<j;i++)
      printf(" %d",a[i]);  
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

The output came was :
[image: The output of the above code]

The output shows that the loop is going up to the key i.e., 42 but prints in a varied manner 1 1 2 1 2 42. Now this is strange.

The required output must be in  format : 1 2 only if input is given 1 2 42 33

Comment: You seem to be testing the array index against 42 in place of the value.

Comment: Learn how to use a *debugger*. Then you can step through the code line by line to see what the error might be.

Comment: Thanks @doynax, since I've done edits in my code and did this 'if(a[j]==42) in place of if(j==42) and then break; _and the loop goes like this_ for(i=0;i<j;i++)'. **But the output is coming out to be 1 only if I'm giving the input as 1 2 42 33**

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int a[10],i,j,arr_size;

   printf("Enter the size of the array");
   scanf("%d",&arr_size);

   printf("Enter the array:");
   for(i=0;i<arr_size;i++)
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);

   //here key is 42
   //so we'll find the key and print the elements up to that
   for(j=0;j<arr_size;j++){
        if(a[j]==42) 
          break;
    }
   //loop for the array up to the key
   for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    printf(" %d",a[i]);  


   return 0; 
}
```

this code will give the requied output.. 1 2

Answer (score 1):

You don't check the array *values* for `42`, you check the *index*.

The reason your loop prints what it prints now, is because the *nested* loops. You print (part of) the array multiple times.

Instead of the nested loop, you could do something simple like

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr_size && a[j] != 42; ++j)
{
    printf(" %d", a[j]);
}
```

I also recommend you add a check to make sure that `arr_size` is not out of bounds for your array.

Comment: @Ajay Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, your code is very efficient one, however I would like to ask a simple question although I don't know much about it. **Since people have been using j++ in the code to increment, how does ++j works in  a loop.** I'd be thankful if you'd give some details about it.

Comment: @AlokKumar The end-result of `j++` versus `++j` is the same, but `j++` needs to return the *old* value of `j` which means there are more operations and possibly a temporary (compiler-generated) variable. I this specific case where the result is ignored a good compiler should be able to optimize both to the same though. Using `++j` is just a habit I have.

Answer (score 1):

The bracket had been misplaced. This what you are looking for:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int a[10],i,j,arr_size;

   printf("Enter the size of the array");
   scanf("%d",&arr_size);

   printf("Enter the array:");
   for(i=0;i<arr_size;i++)
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);

   //here key is 42
   //so we'll find the key and print the elements up to that
   for(j=0;j<arr_size;j++){
        if(a[j]==42) 
          break;
    }
   //loop for the array up to the key
   for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    printf(" %d",a[i]);  


   return 0; 
}
```